# Java/JDBC/Sybase login failure - JZ00L

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, sybase, sqoop

I am having difficulty getting establishing a JDBC connection from my red hat Linux server to our Sybase server.  The error code I get from SQLException is simply "JZ00L: Login failed", followed by "010HA: The server denied your request to use the high availability feature."  I have not requested to use HA, and in fact set the property to false just to be sure.

We have Sqoop installed on this red hat Linux server, and we can create Sqoop jobs which connect and query data just fine from this sybase server.  I am using identical driver, connection, and authentication info in Sqoop and my Java code.

I have seen some references on the internet about code page sometimes causing problems.  But I don't know how to address that in the code.

Below is the java code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
 * A JDBC SELECT (JDBC query) example program.
 */
class Query1 {

     public static void main (String[] args) {
       try {
             SybDriver sd = (SybDriver)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
             System.out.println("Driver loaded");

             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sybase:Tds:srpsyb25:2025","...","...");
             Statement  stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet  rs   = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1 AS One");

             while ( rs.next() ) {
                String col = rs.getString("One");
                System.out.println(col);
             }
             conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            for (SQLException current = e; current != null; current = current.getNextException())
            {
                System.out.println ("=================================================");
                System.out.println("SQL exception : " + current.toString());
                System.out.println("SQL State     : " + current.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("Error Code    : " + current.getErrorCode());

                Throwable t = current.getCause();
                while(t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Unexpected exception! ");
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console output.  Notice my classpath is constrained to that single driver so I believe I'm using that driver:

```
$ java -cp /var/lib/sqoop/jconn4.jar:. Query1
Driver loaded
=================================================
SQL exception : java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Login failed.  Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s).
SQL State     : JZ00L
Error Code    : 0
=================================================
SQL exception : java.sql.SQLWarning: Login failed.

SQL State     : 01ZZZ
Error Code    : 4002
=================================================
SQL exception : java.sql.SQLWarning: 010HA: The server denied your request to use the high-availability feature.  Please reconfigure your database, or do not request a high-availability session.
SQL State     : 010HA
Error Code    : 0
=================================================
SQL exception : java.sql.SQLWarning: Login failed.

SQL State     : 01ZZZ
Error Code    : 4002
=================================================
SQL exception : java.sql.SQLWarning: 010HA: The server denied your request to use the high-availability feature.  Please reconfigure your database, or do not request a high-availability session.
SQL State     : 010HA
Error Code    : 0
$
```

Comment: Error says *"Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s)."* Did you? If not, why? If yes, what did they say?

Comment: There are no additional warning messages.  The code above would dump the SQLWarnings if there were any chained to the exception.  Notice the while loop in the catch clause.  The only error that the system is giving up is the JZ00L message.

Comment: Really? I don't see any calls to `e.getNextException()` or `e.iterator()`. "Chained " exceptions are not the same as `getCause()`.

Comment: The getCause() method is what I am using to get the chained messages, and this I got from the documentation on SQLException. Is that the wrong way to find those messages?

Comment: `Throwable.getCause()` and `SQLException.getNextException()` serves two different purposes. They may both be non-null, referencing different exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Andreas!  That gave me more diagnostic info, albeit weird.  The errors now say that the server is denying my request for a high-availability session.  I did not request one.  I set the property explicitly to false but I still get the error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same exact error,
But for me its just a very bad error message. It was just a bad user/password combination

I solved it by using the correct user credentials